# validar fecha entre un rango excel en python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un archivo de excel como el que muestro a continuación:

| 0 | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | azul | 9.9 | 01/10/2022 | 04/10/2022 |
| 2 | verde | 15.0 | 10/08/2022 | 04/09/2022 |
| 3 | morado | 20.0 | 10/26/2022 | 04/09/2022 |
| 4 | gris | 9.9 | 01/10/2022 | 20/10/2022 |

Lo que necesito es generar una función que recorra el excel y me arroje el valor correspondiente de la columna A si la fecha de hoy esta contenida en el rango de fechas de las columnas C y D.

Que el resultado sea algo similar a:

| 0 | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | verde | 15.0 | 10/08/2022 | 04/09/2022 |
| 3 | morado | 20.0 | 10/26/2022 | 04/09/2022 |

Me muestre solo los que, a día de hoy estan contenido en ese rango de fechas.

Este es el código que llevo hasta ahora, sin embargo no me funciona:

```
  from datetime import date, datetime
  import pandas as pd


fecha=datetime.strftime("2022-08-26 18:46:00", "%d-%m-%Y 
%H:%M:%S")
print('fecha ', fecha)

masterFile='/Users/Documents/Price/masterFile.xlsx'

df=pd.read_excel(masterFile)

mask = (df['C'] > 'fecha') & (df['D'] <= 
'fecha')
df = df.loc[mask]

print(df)
```

Comment: Que intentaste? Que te traba? Las preguntas de tipo "tengo que hacer esto" sin una demostracion de esfuerzo por parte del que hace la pregunta no suelen ser bien recibidas y a menudo terminan cerradas.

Comment: Esto ya te lo habíamos comentado en tu pregunta anterior, siempre es necesario incluir el código que has intentado utilizar y los errores que te impidan realizar la tarea.

Comment: Me parece a mi o estás tratando de comparar un string de fecha, con el string 'fecha'?

Answer (score 0):

Ya he dado con la solución:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime
from operator import index
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

newDate=date.strftime( '%Y-%m-%d')

masterFile='/Users/Documents/Price/masterFile.xlsx'

df=pd.read_excel(masterFile)

df['C']=pd.to_datetime(df['C'])
df['D']=pd.to_datetime(df['D'])

mask=(df['C']<newDate) & (df['D']>=newDate)
df=df.loc[mask]
print(df)
```